# How do I count inside of a javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I stick a counter in a javascript regular expression substitution?

The question is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4214173/823263) for Perl/PCREs.

I've tried the obvious `string.replace(/from/g, "to "+(++count))`, which is no good (the ++count is evaluated once at the start of the string.replace, it seems).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know how many replacements were made?

Comment: No.  I want the replacement text to include the value of a counter that increments with each match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass along a function that is called per match to the replace:

```
// callback takes the match as the first parameter and then any groups as
// additional, left it empty because I'm not using them in the function.
string.replace(/from/g, function() {
  return "to " + (++count);
});
```

I've found this to be an extremely handy tool in replacing complex string portions (like user comments with embedded codes) on the client side to ease the burden a bit on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Using a callback might work:

```
var i = 0;
string.replace(/from/g, function(x){return "to " + i++;})
```

Cheers.