# Regex in java \bword\B which metacharacter win?

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

I am aware that `\bword\B` behaves like a `word\B` using regex in Java. (in terms of matching engine)

Why would it be possible? would not it more reasonable if it was en exception (syntax exception)?
moreover it is also used by oracle in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) tutorial as an explanatory example (`\bdog\B`).
If you do not know the answer, please feel more than free to not respond.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You catch a lot more flies with honey than vinegar.

Comment: Why do you think that `\bword\B` behaves like `word\B`? I don't believe it does. What evidence have you for this?

Comment: @0A0D beautiful comment!

Comment: @Bohemian \bword\B does not match the single word "word" but matches "wordy" for example. try it out.

Comment: @Eugene Yes beautiful but wrong. It does not work like that, try it out "\bword\B" behaves exactly as "word\B"

Comment: @Rollerball I am fully aware ofwhat they match. The fact is that both match "words", but only `word\B` matches "words" in "forewords". That proves they're different. Again I ask, why do you think they are the sane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\B` is the negated version of `\b`. `\B` matches at every position where `\b` does not. Effectively, `\B` matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters.

`\b` allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`. A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not "word characters" are "non-word characters". It is more exact to say `\b` matches before and after an alphanumeric sequence

---

Above is from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

In your example of `\bdog\B`, it will match "doggie" because you asked it to match words and partial words.

`\bdog\b` will fail on "doggie" because "dog" is the whole word whereas "dog" in "doggie" is a partial word.

*It's conditional depending on what it's touching.*

Moreover, `dog\B` will match **"dog"** in the phrase "I have a doggie"

`dog\b` will match **"dog"** in the phrase "I have adog gie"

`dog\B` will not match **"dog"** in the phrase "I have adog gie"

`\bdog\b` will not match **"dog"** in the phrase "I have adog gie"

but `\Bdog\b` will match **"dog"** in the phrase "I have adog gie"

This SO answer provides a [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4214173/195488).