# Powergrep regex replace with a list of words?

Tags: regex, replace, powergrep

I am trying to make this regex work,
need to find every occurance of **#** character in a text, and replace every next occurance with different word, like:
word1, word2, word3...tried this

```
(^.*#.*$)
```

replace with

```
(word1)
(word2)
(word3)
```

or

```
\1word1\2word2\3word3
```

it always replace it with all the words.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace) asked about a similar thing. With a solution in perl. Basically, using a variable counter from the programming language.  Regex doesn't seem to have a flag for a counter of the match.

Comment: Is the number of these words defined?

Comment: First matching word should be replaced with first word in replace-list.

Comment: Yes, but we do or we don't know the size of the replace-list? And at the end of the list the replacements shoud re-start from the begin?

Comment: And -sorry but it's not clear- do you want to replace only the `#` character or the whole line in which `#` appears?