# Exclude some characters from word boundary in javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

`days = /\b\d{2}\b/;
 date = /\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b/;`

2020-12-22 should match date and not days but it matches both.
is it possible to make \b 
 not treat `-` as word boundary?

Comment: Can you specify the order of matching? If not, `var days = /(?:^|[^-])\b(\d{2})\b(?!-)/` should work. Also, you may consider `/\b(?:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b)|(\d{2}))\b/` and check which group contains the value.

Comment: Are you extracting the values from longer text? Then `/\b(?:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b)|(\d{2}))\b/g` looks preferable.

Comment: Show some sample text. Don't make people guess !

Comment: The regex implementation of the internal version of a word boundary is `(?:(?:^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9_]))(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_])|(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9_])(?:$|(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9_])))` It uses lookbehinds which are not available in JS. You could modify it not to use lookbehinds. While your at it, modify it to not consider `-`. Good luck! ( shorthand is `(?:(?:^|(?<=\W))(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?:$|(?=\W)))` )

Comment: `\b(?<!-)\d{2}\b` ?

Comment: @splash58: No, JS regex does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right - I did not look at the tags :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several questions in your current question.

> Is it possible to make `\b` not treat - as word boundary?

See [this tchrist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173) about word boundaries in the *Exploring Boundaries* section. That is how it works, and there is no way to redefine `\b` behavior.

> 2020-12-22 should match date and not days but it matches both.

To match days and avoid matching dates with `days` regex, you would need lookbehind and lookahead - `/\b(?<!-)\d{2}\b(?!-)/` - but JavaScript regex does not support a lookbehind construct. All you can do is use a *consuming pattern* instead that will match the start of string or any char but a hyphen - `(?:^|[^-])`, and use a capturing group around `\d{2}` to *capture* it into a separate group. Note that depending on what you are doing you might also need to use a capturing group in the lookbehind workaround pattern.

If you plan to *extract*, use

```js
var days = /(?:^|[^-])\b(\d{2})\b(?!-)/g;
var s = "25 and 45 on 2017-04-14 and 2017-04-15.";
var res = [], m;
while ((m=days.exec(s)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res)
```

To replace them, use

```js
var days = /(^|[^-])\b(\d{2})\b(?!-)/g;
var s = "25 and 45 on 2017-04-14 and 2017-04-15.";
console.log(s.replace(days, "$1[TAG]$2[/TAG]"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor,  
I am noob at regex, didn't know about look ahead and look behind, will explore that.