# Replacing HTML text elements with increment variable

Tags: regex, vim, notepad++

In the below HTML part, I want to replace, whenever a text is found, with an incremental variable:

```
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >Beautiful Reclessness</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >Comfort vs. Appearance</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >Highlights of the Runway</a>
<ul class='children'>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >Christian Louboutin Show</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >Givenchy F/W 2016</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >Spring by Gaultier</a>
```

To this using the `x++` increment:

```
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >x1</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >x2</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >x3</a>
<ul class='children'>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >x4</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >x5</a>
</li>
<li class="cat-item">
<a href="#" >x6</a>
```

Is there a way in Notepad++ or Vim (looking for in between `> <`) to do find the text contents using REGEX and replace them with an `x` counter?

Comment: The replacement would have to be logic, which I think requires script. It's easily done in Perl or Python, etc

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/4213800/372239

Comment: @D.BenKnoble i corrected my question. Notepad++ or Vim.

Comment: @Leb_Broth provided a vim answer then; I think you'll find it simpler/more extensible, and it doesn't require downloading/setting up extra dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple vim answer:

1. Open the file—`vim filename`
2. Set up a convenience variable—`:let num=1`
3. Do the replaclement—`:g/href/execute printf("normal! citx%d", num) | let num=num+1`

The `:global` command allows one to perform an operation all lines matching a pattern (in this case, `href`). The operation we want to do is change the text inside the `<a>` tag to `x` followed by the contents of `num`, and increment `num`.

`execute` lets us build a command line from strings; I often combine with `printf()` because I find it easier to read. `normal!` is an Ex-command that lets us execute normal-mode commands. `cit` is a vim'ism for "change inside tag" from normal mode. Then we just feed it the appropriate replacement text (`x%d`) and increment the counter.

---

If you're wondering how I came up with this, it's a pretty well-established pattern among vimmers. In practice, it took me probably about a minute to get the whole sequence done (faster if I used it more often), so it isn't one of those "spend 30 minutes trying to write a good regex" answers—this can be done in a live editing session without too much thought, if the person editing has a good grasp of vim fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that helps.

1. [Download python script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/download.shtml)
2. plugins > python script > new script > save as "increment.py"

Develop your regex at regex101 or somewhere else and write the script

```
i=0

def increment(match):
  global i
  i=i+1
  return "x"+str(i)

editor.rereplace('(?<=>)\\b[^><]+', increment)
```

Save and run your script: plugins > python script > scripts > increment

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach on vim:

```
:let c=1 | g/a href="#" >\zs.*\ze</ s//\='x'.c/g | let c+=1
```

Using `\zs` and `\ze` we can select the pattern we want to remove. The counter
will gives the number sequence concatenated with space:

```
\='x'.c ................. concatenate 'x' with the counter
```